Power BI Desktop to Databricks SQL Warehouse SSL_connect: certificate verify failed error
I am trying to connect from Power BI Desktop to my data in Azure Data Lake Gen2 Storage via a Databricks SQL Warehouse. When I input the Server Hostname and HTTP path into the Azure Databricks Connector, I get the following error message:

Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (14) Unexpected response from server during a HTTP connection: SSL_connect: certificate verify failed."

How can I resolve this issue?

If the ODBC driver is unable to reach the certificate revocation list server, for example because of a firewall configuration, it will fail to validate the certificate. This can be resolved by disabling this check.
There is no setting in the Azure Databricks connector for Power BI to 'Trust Server Certificate', however, this behavior can be enabled by adding a new file to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\ODBC Drivers\Simba Spark ODBC Driver directory.
Filename: microsoft.sparkodbc.ini
Contents:
[Driver]
CheckCertRevocation=0

More information here: https://kb.databricks.com/bi/powerbi-proxy-ssl-configuration
